# Jquery как добавить текст к значению из placeholder

Tags: javascript, jquery

Всем привет, есть следующая html разметка.

```
<div class="welcome-text" data-localize="welcomeuser">
  // сюда welcomeuser вставляет текст который берет из json файла
  // мне надо получить значение вот этого текста
</div>
```

Как с помощью jQuery изменить текст который подставляется из значения data-localize ?

пробовал следующим кодом, но он не работает.

```
            $(document).ready(function(){
              $('.welcome-text').html('hello');
            });
```

Comment: Вам нужно добавить к существующему значение атрибута `data-localize` еще символы или вывести значение атрибута `data-localize`?

Comment: да, data-localize="welcomeuser" 

welcomeuser находится в файле json, он читает его и вставляет в html, что видно если посмотреть исходный код страницы, но через атрибут .html jquery он почему то не отображает значение

Comment: сделай [mcve], который будет демонстрировать твою проблему. На данный момент неизвестно что ты используешь, что происходит сейчас, и что ты хочешь чтобы происходило

Comment: я обновил вопрос, и все понятно расписал, повторюсь, мне нужно получить текст который вставляетcя через data-localize в DOM

Comment: @S1lllver, твое обновления ничего не проясняет, так как неизвестно **как именно** вставляется текст: кто его вставляет и в какой момент времени.

Answer (score -1):

```
        $(document).ready(function(){
        var localize = $('.welcome-text').attr('data-localize')
          $('.welcome-text').html(localize);
        });
```

Comment: не сработало, значение берется из json файла, через data-localize и вставляется в дом, мне нужно поменять значение в самом data-localize

Comment: <div class="welcome-text" data-localize="welcomeuser"></div>       
 var localize = $('.welcome-text').attr('data-localize')
 alert(localize);
Он выдает значение атрибута localize, а мне нужен текст который добавляется в страницу, с помощью идентификатора welcomeuser

Comment: всес правку в вопрос

Answer (score -1):

Я правильно понимаю, что нужно что-то подобное?

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.welcome-text').attr('data-localize', 'new-value');
  console.log($('.welcome-text').attr('data-localize'));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="welcome-text" data-localize="welcomeuser"></div>
```

Читать здесь: [.attr()](http://jquery.page2page.ru/index.php5/%D0%A0%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B0_%D1%81_%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B1%D1%83%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B8)

Comment: нет, нужно не значение data-localize, а текст который он вставляет на страницу с помощью своего значения, сейчас внесу правку в вопрос

Comment: поправил вопрос

Answer (score -2):

Ваш код `$('.welcome-text').html('hello');` будет выполняться, только разместите его не в `$(document).ready(function(){});` а после функции, которая заполняет этот div из JSON файла. Что бы получить содержимое div и вставить его в значение атрибута data-localize

```
$(".welcome-text").attr("data-localize",$('.welcome-text').html());
```

но опять таки будет работать при размещении после функции, которая заполняет этот div из JSON файла. А так же если у вас это единственный div с классом welcome-text, если их несколько то значение будет браться из первого div и для выбора нужного нужно будет указать правильный селектор.
Если неизвестно в каком месте подключается функция то отложенный запуск должен решить проблему

```
  $(document).ready(function(){
    setTimeout(function(){
        $('.welcome-text').html('hello');
       },1000);
  });
```